# Socket connect abort from a detached thread

Tags: c++, sockets

I´m building a socket client where I need to implement timeout for connections, read, writes and also timeout for the protocol itself (lack of answer, etc.).

I´m thinking of using a simple timer in a detached thread that will be started on every transaction and then cancelled on transaction completion. This same approach will be used for protocol control using a different timeout.

To test is I did the following simple code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <io.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool timerOn = false;
int currentSocket = 0;


void Timer(int seconds)
{
    int tick = seconds;

    while (tick > 0)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        tick--;
    }

    if (timerOn)
        close(currentSocket);
}

void StartTimer(int seconds)
{
    timerOn = true;
    std::thread t(&Timer, seconds);
    t.detach();
}

void StopTimer()
{
    timerOn = false;
}


void Connect(std::string address, int port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *rp = NULL;
    int sfd, s;

    std::memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;        /* Allow IPV4 or IPV6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;              

    std::string portStr;
    portStr = std::to_string(port);

    s = getaddrinfo(address.c_str(), portStr.c_str(), &hints, &result);

    if (s != 0)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Cannot resolve hostname " << address << gai_strerror(s);
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
    {
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);

        if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

        StartTimer(10);
        int sts = connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
        StopTimer();

        if (sts == 0)
            break;

        close(sfd);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result); /* Object no longer needed */

    if (rp == NULL)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Cannot find server address at " << address << " port " << port;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    currentSocket = sfd;
}


int main()
{
    try
    {
        Connect("192.168.0.187", 9090);
        std::cout << "Connected to server. Congrats!!!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error connecting to server. Aborting." << std::endl;
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Closing the socket on timer is not canceling the 'connect' operation, forcing it to abort with error. I´ve tried also `shutdown(sfd, SHUT_RDWR);` with no success...

Is my approach invalid ? Why is it not working ?

How to force `connect` to abort with error from the detached thread ?

Comment: Not all platforms allow `connect()` to be interrupted by simply closing the socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know of none that do. It may happen sometimes by luck, but it's literally impossible to guarantee. (With just the regular `socket`, `connect`, `close` API, it literally cannot be done. You'd need an API with additional features such as an atomic "connect and then unlock" function.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Windows allows `connect()` to be aborted by closing the socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Using what API? Inspecting the other thread's stack to confirm it's blocked in `connect` with a debug API? You certainly can't do it with just `close`, `closesocket`, and `connect`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think what he's saying is if thread A is blocked in `connect()` and thread B calls `closesocket()` on the same socket handle, then the `connect()` will fail and thread A will unblock.

Comment: @keithmo What API would allow you to know that thread A was blocked in `connect()` though? If you call `closesocket()` *before* thread A manages to block in `connect()`, terrible things will happen. So you can *never* do that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's why I used the word "if", as in "...if thread A is blocked..." We're talking about two different things. Does the API allow one to abort a `connect()` by closing the socket (my point)? Yes. Is it fraught with peril (your point)? Also yes. There are other, practical ways (nonblocking sockets or an overlapped `ConnectEx()`) to enforce connect timeouts.

Comment: @keithmo An API doesn't "allow" you to do something if it *might* happen by luck but also might result in unpredictable behavior. An API allows you to do something if it provides a way to safely do that thing that doesn't result in unavoidable race conditions that could produce unpredictable results. Yes, it might happen by accident if you write broken code, but the API doesn't allow you to rely on being able to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Closing the socket on timer is not canceling the 'connect' operation, forcing it to abort with error.

Whoa! You absolutely can't do that. There's no possible way to know that the thread is actually blocked in `connect` (as opposed to being about to call `connect`) when you close the socket. Releasing a resource in one thread while another thread is, or might be, using it is a recipe for disaster.

Imagine this happens:

1. A thread is about to call `connect`, so it arranges for a timeout.
2. The timeout expires and the socket is closed.
3. A thread in some library creates a new socket to use for some reason of its own, getting the same socket descriptor.
4. The thread that was about to call `connect` finally gets scheduled and calls `connect` -- connecting the library's socket! Disaster.

You have two choices:

1. Use a non-blocking `connect` operation.
2. Use something like a signal to interrupt the thread that calls `connect`.

But I have to wonder why you are bothering. Why do you need to abort the connect? If you need to do something else if the connect hasn't succeeded before the timeout, just go ahead and do it.

Comment: "*why you are bothering*" - because without a timeout, `connect()` may take a long time to exit with an error. Depending on the number of hops needed to reach the destination, an answer may take awhile to discover one way or another.  As fast as modern networks are nowadays, they are still not instantaneous. If you don't abort it after the timeout, it may still come back later and say "oh yeah, I finally made it", but you already moved on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So what? Why is that a problem? Even if you do abort it, it still could succeed -- in fact, it may have already succeeded, you just haven't received the final packet saying so (or the other side hasn't received it yet, but irrevocably will receive it and then send a response that you receive, completing the connect attempt). So there's nothing you can do about the possibility that you will abort a connect that has already (or may later) succeed.

Comment: even if it succeeds at the lower level, the higher level socket will have been aborted/closed, so any subsequent traffic should fail with a reset response.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can easily get that behavior by closing the socket immediately (without reading anything) if the `accept` completes successfully but the timeout has already expired. You can't avoid the other side seeing a normal close no matter what you do.

Comment: So, seens that this approach is not valid. I´ll rewrite all to use non-blocking `connect` as suggested.